# If statement in R: Vector of tests and actions

Tags: r

Some sample data:

```
ID        S1Qual    S2Qual    S3Qual    S1        S2        S3
1         1         0         1         7         8         7
2         1         1         1         6         6         8
3         0         1         1         7         8         8
...
```

S1Qual, S2Qual, and S3Qual denote the quality of S1PS, S2PS, and S3PS, respectively.  If `[n, S1Qual] == 1`, I want to keep `[n, S1PS]`; if `[n,S1Qual] == 0`, I want to set `[n,S1PS] == NA`.

I have the following code:

```
n <- 1

while (n <= number.of.rows) {

    if (data$S1Qual[n] == 0) {data$S1[n] <- NA}
    if (data$S2Qual[n] == 0) {data$S2[n] <- NA}
    if (data$S3Qual[n] == 0) {data$S3[n] <- NA}


  n <- n+1

}
```

This does what I wanted, but I was hoping there was a more efficient/concise way (in the real dataframe, there are many more than three of these S/SQual pairs).  Searching around has lead me to `ifelse()` and `apply()`, both of which seem close but not quite right for what I want, unless I'm thinking about it wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
cols <- paste0("S", 1:3)
data[,cols][data[,paste0(cols,"Qual")]==0] <- NA
```

Note: change the vector `1:3` to match your actual number of columns.

Comment: Looks awesome, but when I try it, I get `Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , cols, value = list(c(-18.948082,  :
  provided 2352 variables to replace 6 variables`

Comment: @PyNewb you're correct, the `ifelse` approach is misleading. Please consider the other option (now the only option). :-)

Comment: It's doing what the [data1==0] brackets is doing in the third line of my answer. (Another reason to keep things simple in R.)

Comment: Hah, unfortunately I don't understand what the third line of your code is doing either.  Are you selecting not columns, nor rows, but POSITIONS?  Is that what's happening?

Comment: I've put a line by line explanation in my answer below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I find it's easier to understand R code if you keep things simple. And it helps future me who has forgotten everything.

You could make a copy, and do a simple replace on any item that is equal to zero (which is what Ferdinand has done... His is more clever):

```
data1 <- data[,c(2:4)]
data2 <- data[,c(5:7)]
data2[data1==0] <- NA
data[,c(5:7)] <- data2
```

---

**Edit for explanation:**

The first two lines create equal dimension data frames. Because they have the same dimensions you can use the index from `data1` to refer to `data2`.

The magic happens on the third line (technically called filtering). If an element in `data1` is 0, it will return TRUE, otherwise FALSE. The third line says "if an element in `data1` is 0, then return that index from `data2`." Eg, using the example data above, if the element at `data1[1,2]` is zero (it is), then assign NA to `data2[1,2]`.

The last line replaces the old 3x3 submatrix with the new one.

Comment: Great answer!  Wish I could pick two solutions.

Comment: Thanks, they're both pretty much the same. :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation--helps a ton.  Would upvote you if I had enough reputation, hah.

Comment: Good explanation. I'm upvoting for PyNewb :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
mydata<-mtcars[1:10,1:4]


    mydata
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp
Mazda RX4         21.0   6 160.0 110
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110
Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175
Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105
Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245
Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62
Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123

fi<-as.list(names(mydata)[1:2]) # first two columns to be used as base 
se<-as.list(names(mydata)[3:4]) # second two columns which will be replaced based on first two cols
kk<-Map(function(x,y) mydata[[y]]<-ifelse(mydata[[x]]>4,1,mydata[[y]]),fi,se) # for your example replace >4 with `==0` and 1 with NA 
ll<-t(do.call(rbind,kk))
mydata[,3:4]<-ll
```

> mydata

```
                  mpg cyl disp hp
Mazda RX4         21.0   6    1  1
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6    1  1
Datsun 710        22.8   4    1 93
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6    1  1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8    1  1
Valiant           18.1   6    1  1
Duster 360        14.3   8    1  1
Merc 240D         24.4   4    1 62
Merc 230          22.8   4    1 95
Merc 280          19.2   6    1  1
```

For your data:

```
fi<-as.list(names(mydata)[1:3]) # first three columns to be used as base 
se<-as.list(names(mydata)[4:6]) # second three columns which will be replaced based on first three cols
kk<-Map(function(x,y) mydata[[y]]<-ifelse(mydata[[x]]==0,NA,mydata[[y]]),fi,se)
ll<-t(do.call(rbind,kk))
mydata[,4:6]<-ll
```